# Files not showing in Xcode project navigator after switching to branch

Tags: xcode, git, git-branch

After i switched to one of the branches from master branch, Xcode is not showing files in project navigator and also showing no shceme. Although I can checkout to master branch again, Xcode is not showing files in project navigator and also showing no shceme. Any fix pls.

[image]

Comment: Happened to me today. Killing Xcode and restarting did fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

`pod install` solves the problem.